# how to require a file in a model, YII2

Tags: model, yii2, require

i want to add a PHPExcel class to a model in Yii2,
i've used this code to require IOFactory.php in model :

```
require_once(Yii::getAlias('@vendor/excel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'));
```

but when i want to use that class , i get this error message :

```
Class 'backend\models\PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found
```

could you tell me where is my mistake ?

Comment: how do you use the class?

Comment: like this `$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(Yii::getAlias('@vendor/excel/05featuredemo.xls'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use require classes in Yii2 project. All required libraries should be installed by [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), or locate among project files. At the beginning composer may be difficult to understand, but him advantages is tremendous. You be able to install libraries just typing one command!

[Read more about autoloading in Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-autoloading.html).

In this case you can install PHPExcel by add to `composer.json` this line:

```
"require": {
  ...
  "phpexcel/phpexcel": "1.8.1",
  ...
}
```

Next you run `composer update` and you can be able to use simple

`$phpExcel = new \PHPExcel_IOFactory();`

Comment: what if i want to add another class to model , which is not php excel?

Comment: i should say, codes works perfectly, when use it in a view page, what is different of model and view?

Comment: Nothing. It's single application. Try add `use \PHPExcel_IOFactory;` under model namespace, or use `\PHPExcel_IOFactory::load` in code. Pay attention to `\\` symbol. It says at what level find a class.

Comment: perfect, does `use \PHPExcel_IOFactory;` works for every classes? i mean can i use such this method for any class that i want to add?

Comment: Yes. In every class in project. Also you will be write `use` for yours classes.